# How do I copy portions of an xml file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that is relatively large.  The client sends me a complete file even though I only need portions of the file.  As a result, I would like to parse out the parts that I need and process this new file.

Here is a portion of the xml

```
<Activity>
    <RetailFormat>ABC</RetailFormat>
    <FeedDate>2014-02-06 21:01:10</FeedDate>
    <ActivityId>665507</ActivityId>
    <ActivityTitle>ABC 3.9.14 Hawaii </ActivityTitle>
    <StartDate>2014-03-09</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2014-03-15</EndDate>
    <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
    <EndTime>23:59:59</EndTime>
    <JANumber>0</JANumber>
    <PlanItemNo>0</PlanItemNo>
    <ChannelType>Circular</ChannelType>
    <Version>
    </Version>
</Activity>
```

I have a list of ActivityIDs that I need to search for.  If the ActivityID is in the list I want to copy the entire Activity into a new file.  If not, I want to move to the next Activity.  The  is actually several hundred lines down from the start tag.  I have not worked with xml other than to manually parse out sections.  I don't know if there is a programmatic way to deal with this issue.  Also, I need perhaps 15K lines out of this file.  The file has 1.3MM lines in it.  By limiting the size of the processed file, I can cut my processing time dramatically.

I am looking for the most efficient way to attack this problem.  I am fine with doing it manually for a while, but I would prefer to limit it sooner rather than later.

Comment: A big 'if' here.. but 'if' the file is formatted, ie. line-per-line rather than as one huge unformatted text/xml file, then you could treat it like a normal file and use a stream reader until you hit a line that matches what you're looking for, that would save memory and be very fast. Option two, linq-to-xml and follow this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387013(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is very big and memory use is a concern, you should use a SAX parser (in your language of choice - add it to your tags). SAX does not work with trees, so you have to rebuild the subtrees yourself while your parse. The advantage is that it doesn't have to load the whole XML into memory. You only store what you really need.

A SAX parser is an event-based XML parser which will read your file sequentially and produce events. Events are handled in methods like `startElement(...)`, `startDocument(...)`, `endElement(...)`, `characters(...)`, etc. You have to write a handler to capture the events you wish to handle implementing these methods.

Your handler will have to implement `startElement()`, `characters()` and `endElement()`, and use instance variables to save relevant data you will need between methods (ex: current-element, an array to store your code fragments, etc.

If memory is not a problem, you can use DOM or XSLT. With DOM you can use `getElementsByTagName("Activity")` to retrieve an array of `<Activity>` subtrees, and then check the `<ActivityID>` using DOM methods on that subtree. Then you can copy the subtrees you want, adding them to another root, or removing the ones you don't want from the current root.

Using XSLT you can write a XML template which selects all `<Activity>` nodes with an XPath expression such as `//Activity`, check the ID comparing `//Activity/ActivityID` to your list of IDs and producing a result tree with only the `Activity` nodes you want.

Inform the language you are using and I might be able to send you some examples.

Comment: I am programming language agnostic.  I basically will learn the language as I have done with a few others.  My big issue is when I have done the manual parsing in the past, I have reduced 70 meg files down to under 5.  Is there a language that works well for this type of operation?

Comment: The solution I described above is the way you would solve the problem using a SAX parser in Java or Ruby. NSXMLParser in Objective-C also does something similar. I'm not aware of anything like this in C# or LINQ, but I'm not really a .NET programmer and I haven't used C# in a long time, so I might be wrong. You might be able to read a XML stream in C# in a memory-efficient way using XmlReader.  XLinq uses an object model like DOM and has to load the full XML in memory before processing (as far as I know, that's still true in Linq to XML).

Comment: I have an example in Java which uses two classes (one to start the parser, another to handle the tag events) to extract data based on child nodes in a XML source file that has the same structure as yours. I'll upload it to github now and publish the link shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your help helderdarocha

Comment: [This is a simple example in Java](https://github.com/helderdarocha/JavaXMLExamples/tree/master/SAXExample2). This is the [source XML](https://github.com/helderdarocha/JavaXMLExamples/blob/master/SAXExample2/src/main/resources/source.xml) which resembles yours. It's a list of movies. [This class](https://github.com/helderdarocha/JavaXMLExamples/blob/master/SAXExample2/src/main/java/br/com/argonavis/extractnodeswithsax/ExtractMovieSaxHandler.java) is where the tag events are handled.

Comment: The search parameters are hardwired. You could easily adapt this to your XML simply replacing `Movie` with `Activity`, `Director` with `ActivityID`, and using `STRICT = true`.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I introduced an error in the code while making it simpler. I'll fix it and commit the correction (a tag is missing in the result).

Comment: Fixed it. This is the result if you run it as is (selects three nodes):
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Movies>
    <Movie>...</Movie>
    <Movie>...</Movie>
    <Movie>...</Movie>
</Movies>` where the `...` represent the original content of the selected nodes.

Comment: Okay I have made a few changes.  I changed Movie to Activity and Director to ActivityID. What I do not see is anything that tells me what file to apply this to.  I am missing something?

Comment: The file is loaded in [this class](https://github.com/helderdarocha/JavaXMLExamples/blob/master/SAXExample2/src/main/java/br/com/argonavis/extractnodeswithsax/SAXReaderExample.java). If you set up the same environment, you can just add your file to the same directory, and replace `"source.xml"` with the name of your file.

Comment: Thanks.  I have the two classes set up.  A few questions.  The line package br.com.argonavis.extractnodeswithsax; should be changed to what?  Do I need to save this class to a particular location or does it just need to be on my server?  I am running this on a Mac but I can easily move this to a Windows server environment, does that matter?  Finally, do I need to compile this some way or do I just run the class that selects the file?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about this. Those two classes should be compiled and run in a Java environment. It's very easy to set up if you install an environment. The code can compile and run using maven. If you are on a mac, you might be able to install Maven using `brew install maven`, and then, enter the project directory and run `mvn install`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I configured the app to be executable (since that's an example I use in class and students usually just run it in NetBeans), but I can do that and update the `pom.xml` (maven configuration) file in GIT. Then you just update it and run `mvn install` again.

Comment: okay I hope this is my last question.  I am unable to compile and I suspect it is because this line : package br.com.argonavis.extractActivitywithsax;  Do I need to put this into a directory on my laptop?

Comment: No. Packages are used for namespaces in Java. Usually they follow the convention `reverse.dns.application`, but you can safely remove the line. What happens is that when you compile Java code (*.java files), it will create a directory structure in the destination directory like `/reverse/dns/application` where the .class files will be located.

Comment: So if you wish, remove the whole line (package ...;) from both files, and place them in some directory. Then you can use any compiler you wish. When you compile you will have two .class files. You can run the app simply using `java SAXReaderExample`.

Comment: The file name is hardwired in the SAXReaderExample class. It will look for a file relative to the directory where you run the app. If it doesn't work, feel free to ask me anything. I'll have free time this weekend and I may be able to adapt it for you.

Comment: I am getting close I can feel it.  Here is the error when I try to compile xmlselect.java 1 error found:
File: /Users/timvavra/Desktop/XML/xmlselect.java  [line: 17]
Error: /Users/timvavra/Desktop/XML/xmlselect.java:17: class SAXReaderExample is public, should be declared in a file named SAXReaderExample.java
Should I be saving this with a .class?

Comment: Yes. The .java files should have the same name as the class (if it's declared public, which is the case). If the public class is called SAXReaderExample, the file has to be called SAXReaderExample.java (case matters)

Comment: so pom.java should be SAXReaderExample.java

Comment: `pom.xml` is actually a Maven (build tool) configuration file. Since that code does not depend on third party libraries, you don't really need Maven. There are only two *.java files. You can download them individually from the git repository, or cut and paste them in .java files which have the exact same name as the class name. Then you can use a command line javac compiler and try javac *.java. If all goes well you will have two .class files.

Comment: I got it to start.  I am using DrJava to compile and run the script.  It starts but does not complete.  I am going to reduce the file side first and then retry.  The problem is that the source file is 1.5 MM rows of data.  It may be too much to start.

Comment: You could add a feedback line informing the number of `Activity` elements read so far. Declare a new variable after `private boolean skip = false;` like this: `private long count = 0;`, and in the `startElement` method, inside the `if` that checks if the element is an `Activity` insert the line `System.out.println(++count);` . Then you will print the number of tags processed so far.

Comment: Yes. Using a smaller file to test is a good idea. Unless your result file is also very big, there shouldn't be memory problems since only the matching subtrees are stored.